# R - Need help on Multi-State Markov and Block Bootstrap please

Tags: r, statistics-bootstrap, markov

First of all I have to stay that I am very new to R and never had an experience with Markov Analysis or Bootstrap before. I have been researching about these for some time but couldn't find a solution so decided to post this question.

I have a animal movement data, which consist of different states coded in numbers such as 1, 2, 3. I would like to run the Multi-State Markov to yield the transition probability matrix, but as my data consist of replications for each subject (for example, Animal 1 was tested 3 times, Animal 2 was tested 3 times, and Animal 3 was tested 4 times), and each subject contains a panel data (Time 0-2). Here is an example of what my data look like:

```
data <- read.csv("test1.csv", header=T)
data
   Animal Time DV
1    1     0    1
2    1     1    2
3    1     2    3
4    1     0    1
5    1     1    3
6    1     2    2
7    1     0    3
8    1     1    1
9    1     2    1
10   2     0    2
11   2     1    1
12   2     2    2
13   2     0    2
14   2     1    3
15   2     2    1
16   2     0    2
17   2     1    2
18   2     2    1
19   3     0    2
20   3     1    1
21   3     2    1
22   3     0    2
23   3     1    1
24   3     2    2
25   3     0    1
26   3     1    2
27   3     2    1
28   3     0    2
29   3     1    3
30   3     2    3
```

As each subject contains replications, I would like to run bootstrap to resample a subject before performing msm. I have looked up codes to run bootstrap and Markov analysis but when writing a script to create initial values for qmatrix, it returned the following error:

```
Q <- rbind(c(0.33, 0.33, 0.33), 
            c(0.33, 0.33, 0.33), 
            c(0.33, 0.33, 0.33))

Q.crude <- crudeinits.msm(DV ~ Time, Animal, data=data, qmatrix=Q)

Error in msm.check.times(time, subject, state) : 
     Observations within subjects 1, 2, 3 are not ordered by time
```

Could anyone please suggest how to fix this please? Also I am planning to use the following scripts for bootstrap but not sure if it was the right ones and what should be put for "l".

```
boot.f <- function(data){
              msm(DV ~ Time, subject=Animal, data = data, qmatrix = Q.crude, 
              gen.inits=T, death=F, exacttimes=T)}

boot <- tsboot(data, boot.f, R=1000, l=?, sim="fixed")
```

My ultimate goal is to get averages of transition probabilities and SDs for each transition. Please if anyone could shed some light or give any suggestion on how to achieve this, I would very much appreciate it.

Answer (score 4):

The error message given by function `crudeinits.msm` (which would also be given by function `msm`) is due to the fact that the function expects that the data is indexed (what the package refers to as a "subject") by the second argument, which you are passing as `Animal`. Since your data consists of replicates for the same animal, the format does not match what the package expects.

Here is some code, implementing everything that you want, including the bootstrap. The implementation is quite preliminary, using for example using a "for loop", for simplicity, and can obviously be optimized (e.g., by running the bootstrap in parallel). Note that the call to `msm`, to perform the estimation of the parameters, is wrapped in a try-catch, since sometimes the estimation ends up failing (I guess due to the small number of animals considered here). One important detail is that I have set the option `obstype` as being equal to 1, corresponding to the case of "panel data", in which each time-series was observed at regular time-instants, since this seems to be the case of your data; see the documentation of `msm` for details. For the data that you provide, some setup needs to be done, to add the identification corresponding to the "subject" field (as explained in the code below). For the analysis, the data is obtained by sampling with replacement 3 time-series per animal.

```
# File containing the example data that was provided in the question
Data <- read.csv("test1.csv", header = TRUE)

# Add the ids of the replicates for each individual
addReplIds = function(D) {
    # Get the indices of the boundaries
    ind_bnds <- which(diff(D$Time) < 0)
    return (cbind(repl = unlist(mapply(
        rep, 
        x = 1:(length(ind_bnds) + 1), 
        length.out = diff(c(0, ind_bnds, nrow(D))), 
        SIMPLIFY = FALSE)), D))
}
library(dplyr)
Data <- as.data.frame(Data %>% group_by(Animal) %>% do(addReplIds(.)))
# Combine the animal and the replicate ids to identify a "sample" (a time-series)
Data <- mutate(Data, sample_id = paste(Animal, repl, sep = "."))

# Pack header data, linking each "sample" to the animal to which it belongs.
Header_data <- subset(Data, Time == 0, select = c("Animal", "sample_id"))

# Number of bootstrap iterations
N_bootp <- 1000
# Number of time-series to be sampled per animal
n_time_series_per_animal <- 3
# The duration of each time-series
t_max <- 2

library(msm)
lst_Bootp_results <- list()
for (i in seq(1, N_bootp)) {
    # Obtain the subject ids to be included in the data sample
    Data_sample <- as.data.frame(
        Header_data %>% group_by(Animal) %>% 
            do(sample_n(., n_time_series_per_animal, replace = TRUE)))
    # Add a column representing the "subject" (index for each time-series in 
    # this data sample)
    Data_sample <- cbind(Data_sample, subject = 1:nrow(Data_sample))
    # Add the actual data
    Data_sample <- merge(Data, Data_sample, by = c("Animal", "sample_id"))
    # Sort the data by time (as required by the `msm` package)
    Data_sample <- arrange(Data_sample, subject, Time)

    P_mat <- tryCatch({
        # Estimation
        Q_0 <- matrix(data = 1 / 3, nrow = 3, ncol = 3)
        model <- msm(DV ~ Time, subject = subject, data = Data_sample, 
                     qmatrix = Q_0, obstype = 1, gen.inits = TRUE)

        # Obtain the estimated transition probability matrix (over one time-unit)
        P_model <- pmatrix.msm(model)
        class(P_model) <- "matrix"
        P_model
    }, error = function(e) {
        warning(sprintf("[ERROR] %s", e), call. = FALSE, immediate. = TRUE)
        return (NULL)
    })

    if (!is.null(P_mat) && all(is.finite(P_mat)) && all(abs(rowSums(P_mat) - 1) < 1e-3))
        lst_Bootp_results[[i]] <- cbind(ind_bootp = i, 
                                        current_state = rownames(P_mat), 
                                        as.data.frame(P_mat))
}
cat(sprintf("Estimation failed in %d / %d of the bootstrap samples\n", 
            sum(sapply(lst_Bootp_results, is.null)), N_bootp))
Bootp_results <- do.call(rbind, lst_Bootp_results)
```

Since this is a 3-state model, the transition probabilities out of each state can be represented in a 3-vertex simplex (using package `ggtern`), such that the results can be plotted using the following code:

```
# Generate figure
library(ggtern)
library(ggplot2)

Bootp_plot <- Bootp_results
Bootp_plot[, "current_state"] <- paste("When in ", Bootp_plot[, "current_state"], sep = "")
colnames(Bootp_plot)[3:5] = c("S1", "S2", "S3")
# Filter out points in the boundaries, otherwise the confidence regions 
# cannot be estimated by 'ggtern'
Bootp_plot <- subset(Bootp_plot, (S1 != 0) & (S2 != 0) & (S3 != 0))
cat(sprintf("Plotting %d data points (from %d)\n", nrow(Bootp_plot), nrow(Bootp_results)))

ggtern(data = Bootp_plot, aes(x = S1, y = S2, z = S3)) + 
    geom_point(size = rel(2), alpha = 0.5) +
    geom_confidence(breaks = c(0.5, 0.9, 0.95)) + 
    facet_wrap(~ current_state, nrow = 1) + 
    ggtitle(sprintf("Experimental data (%d time-series per individual, %d bootstrap samples)\n", 
                    n_time_series_per_animal, N_bootp)) + 
    labs(fill = "") + theme_rgbw() + labs(shape = "")
ggsave("bootstrap_results-data.pdf", height = 5, width = 9)
```

producing:

[image: Bootstrap results]

where the lines correspond to 50%, 90% and 95% confidence regions (see the documentation of package `ggtern`).

Finally, if you want to retrieve stats out of the bootstrap results, here is some code. It computes the lower and upper values for 95% confidence intervals, and the median, as usual when doing a bootstrap; it is trivial to modify to obtain the average and SDs of the transition probabilities, although I would recommend using the confidence intervals:

```
# To calculate summary statistics, melt the data
Bootp_results <- melt(Bootp_results, id.vars = c("ind_bootp", "current_state"), 
                      variable.name = "next_state", value.name = "prob")
Bootp_stats <- as.data.frame(
    Bootp_results %>% group_by(current_state, next_state) %>% 
        summarize(lower_prob = quantile(prob, probs = 0.025, names = FALSE), 
                  median_prob = median(prob), 
                  upper_prob = quantile(prob, probs = 0.975, names = FALSE))
)
```

producing:

```
current_state next_state lower_prob median_prob upper_prob
      State 1    State 1 0.27166496   0.4635482  0.7735892
      State 1    State 2 0.12566126   0.3105540  0.4474771
      State 1    State 3 0.05316077   0.2012626  0.3948478
      State 2    State 1 0.24483769   0.4193336  0.6249328
      State 2    State 2 0.15762565   0.3148918  0.4466980
      State 2    State 3 0.06223002   0.2612689  0.5133920
      State 3    State 1 0.17428479   0.4434651  0.7183298
      State 3    State 2 0.06044651   0.2599676  0.4684195
      State 3    State 3 0.06399818   0.2777778  0.5997379
```

Comment: Thanks you so much for your help. I really appreciate it. However when I try running the code you suggested, it returned an error message as:

Comment: Sorry I am new to this forum and didn't know there is a character limit in the comment. I have posted it as an "Answer" instead. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @tguzella Greetings. Please help I am facing a strange problem.Y<- msm(x) function runs without error and gives good result but boot.msm(y) gives error: Error in msm.check.times(mf$"(time)", mf$"(subject)", mf$"(state)") : 
  Observations within subjects 47, 52, 352 and others are not ordered by time